# Vaadin Flow and Keycloak Server: connection lost, trying to reconnect

Tags: keycloak, vaadin-flow

we have implemented a vaadin application using latest 14 LTS version of Vaadin and integrated with Keycloak 8. The configuration works and when we first start the application the user is forwarded to keycloak login page and then redirected to vaadin app.

When keycloak token expires, the application doesn't redirect to keycloak as it runs in background a heartbeat ajax request and tries to redirect to keycloak login page. We first getting a CORS error from keycloak which some how can be resolved from Keycloak I assume, but even though this work, the redirect doesn't redirect us to keycloak login, as it is ajax request

When we inspect the page we have this flow:

**Heartbeat URL**
URL: http://localhost:8090/?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=3

**Application Login Page**
URL: http://localhost:8090/sso/login

**Keycloak Login URL**
URL: https://keycloak_url/auth/realms/htp/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=web&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8090%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=6ed652f2-dd7e-4398-bc60-798f6d055f69&login=true&scope=openid due to access

and the result is a not a json response in a window in application having the keycloak login form instead of redirecting

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: I am having a similar environment. When I restart my application, redirection to login page in opened browser windows from before is not done, too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is missing.

Comment: You can find a minimal reproducable example here: https://github.com/karkaletsis/vaadin-keycloak

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377408