# how to handle SSO redirect in Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10, vaadin14

We have a Vaadin 14 (Flow) application which is fronted by an Apache reverse proxy that integrates with [Gluu](https://www.gluu.org/) for authentication.

When the session is not valid anymore, either because of session timeout or a logout in another browser tab/window, the Apache server will send a redirect to the Gluu server to let the user log in again.
However when this happens for an internal Vaadin [XHR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) call (Ajax request), Vaadin does not seem to handle this response very well, and shows an "Invalid JSON response from server" error.

What I want is either for Vaadin to set the browser location to the URL indicated in the redirect, or refresh the page (maybe with a confirmation message between) in which case the browser will nicely follow the redirect.  How can this be achieved, or what other options are there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the XHR response cannot be parsed as JSON, Vaadin will look for a `Vaadin-Refresh` string anywhere inside the response text. If it's present, then Vaadin will reload the page instead of showing an error message. Optionally, you can use the format `Vaadin-Refresh: <url>` which will make Vaadin redirect to `<url>` rather than reloading the current location.

You can configure Gluu to include this string as e.g. a HTML comment in the response that is sent when the user needs to log in.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.  Is there a reason that Vaadin doesn't detect the standard 30X HTTP status code combined with `Location:` header in the response instead of requiring this custom solution?

Comment: The browser automatically follows any regular 30x redirect without directly involving the caller (e.g. Vaadin). Furthermore, a 30x redirect may still in theory lead to a response that contains the JSON that Vaadin expects, whereas the `Vaadin-Refresh` token serves as a clear indication that the page should be reloaded rather than trying to interpret the response.

Comment: I understand.  Technically this would be possible with a [request option in the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/redirect) set to value `manual`, in recent browsers (maybe something for Vaadin 15+?).  Vaadin could then be configured to set the browser location for redirects to a specific URL (and simply follow other redirects that may indeed lead to the expected JSON).  This would cover cases where the SSO's login page is not directly under the application developer's control.

Comment: Excellent idea to configure that a specific redirect URL should cause a top-level navigation! I also realized that the content type of the response could be used as an indicator. Furthermore, XHR redirects can be detected (but not prevented or intercepted) by looking for a change in `responseURL`. I documented this idea in https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/7679.

Comment: I wanted to use this `Vaadin-Refresh: <url>` for another use case, but it seems the request gets cancelled by the browser (at least Chrome), even though it is same origin.  Only the basic `Vaadin-Refresh` seems to work properly these days (at least using Vaadin 14).

Comment: The `Vaadin-Refresh` mechanism might be broken/removed in Vaadin 22, as I'm seeing users get "Invalid JSON from server" errors after the upgrade even though the response is an html page that includes `<!-- Vaadin-Refresh -->`

Comment: I haven't heard about any such regression but I have heard about others using the refresh mechanism successfully just last week. Could you please open an issue in the Flow repository with any additional information that might help reproduce the issue?